# Can you really email users about payment methods in App Store and Play Store?

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store, payment

I have an app and as everyone, I don't want to pay 30% to either big company.
Denial of emailing users about alternative payments was removed from the apple dev guidelines a few years ago.
What I'm doing now is that they can register through me manually, later on on a webpage and they get an email with payment information and links to the apps in the stores.
Is it possible that the registration happens in the app, and the email obtained there would be used to send out the same email?

I reread the guidelines, if I understand it well, if you can purchase eg. this subscription in the app, I can email my user about alternative payment even if they registered in the app.